# How to stop Edge restoring tabs after a crash

Tags: microsoft-edge

If Microsoft Edge crashes or is forcibly stopped, when you restart it you see the tabs that were open before. I need to stop this behaviour.

Several web pages say that you do this by adding:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\MicrosoftEdge\Recovery\AutoRecover
```

and

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\MicrosoftEdge\Recovery\AutoRecover
```

to the Windows registry, and giving them both the value 2. However, this has no effect on the two PCs I have tried it on (both Windows 10).

Is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: Are your Edge settings configured to something other than "Previous Session"? From [TechNet](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/forum/all/stop-microsoft-edge-re-opening-with-yesterdays/4d5cc94d-e473-4a62-9584-131307d73ab5)

Comment: Open Microsoft Edge with: New tab page.
Open new tabs with: A blank page